# ObjectChanged Event not Bubbling for ValuesAdded/ValuesRemoved

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am trying to reduce the number of event listeners attached to my collaborative models. In order to do this, I have started listening to the ObjectChanged event instead of specific event types and delegating to other handlers. However it doesn't look like the ObjectChanged event is being bubbled properly for the ValuesAdded/ValuesRemoved changes on CollaborativeLists.

```
function onObjectChanged(e)
{
    log('Changed: ', e);
}

// Placeholder, called when we load our doc through the realtime api. 
function onDocLoaded(doc)
{
    var docModel = doc.getModel();
    var docRoot = docModel.getRoot();

    console.log('Drive document loaded: ', window.performance.now());

    if (docRoot.has('testMap'))
    {
        docRoot.delete('testMap');
    }

    docRoot.set('testMap', docModel.createMap());

    var testMap = docRoot.get('testMap');
    console.assert(testMap, 'Test map required');

    docRoot.addEventListener(gapi.drive.realtime.EventType.OBJECT_CHANGED, onObjectChanged);

    var testList = docModel.createList();
    testMap.set('testList', testList);
    console.assert(testList, 'Test list required');

    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        console.log('Begin Push');
        testList.push('This is a test string');
        console.log('End Push');
    }, 1000);
}
```

The code above is run on doc load and demonstrates the problem. In this case, I would expect two ObjectChanged events to be fired (first for the list being set on the map and second for the string push into the list). The first event fires correctly, however the list push does not trigger an ObjectChanged event on either the 'docRoot' or the 'testMap'. As both of these are ancestors of the testList an event should be bubbled to them (based on https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/handle-events#event_bubbling).

The ObjectChanged event however IS fired on the testList, so it looks like there is an issue with only the bubbling portion.

Is there a way of ensuring that the event bubbling will occur? Additionally, for events that are bubbling up, is there a way to stop bubbling partway?

Comment: I have no solution but I can confirm that I observe the same problem.

Regarding stopping bubbling, the reference documentation seem to indicate that ObjectChangedEvent is ultimately derived from goog.events.Event, which defines stopPropagation. However, I just tried that and it gave me a 'has no method' error. That may warrant a separate question.